# Independence of the components of an Ito process

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, independence, stochastic-differential-equations

If $X_t = (X^i_t)_{i \leq n}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ solves an SDE of the form

$$dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dB_t$$

Does it hold that each of the real valued random variables $X^i_t$ and $X^j_t$ are independent for each $t$ provided $i \neq j$? It's true for Brownian motion, and I'm mainly interested in the higher dimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, but I was curious if it just works in general.

Comment: It's not even the case for Brownian motion but only for 'standard' BM whose covariance matrix is the identity. For other covariance matrices you will explore dependences among the components even for BM. That being said, obviously you should not expect components of a multivariate diffusion to be indepent. Btw, why should people study multivariate SDEs in the first place, if their components were always independent?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, after thinking about it, its a bit of an ask for this to be true. What about for $X^i_t, X^j_s$ for different times $s,t$? Can I use some kind of Martingale property or maybe Markov property?